# Android Auto language tied to phone?

Tags: languages, voice-recognition, text-to-speech, android-auto

I have a Nexus 6P and just got a car with android auto, i use my phone and most of my things with English language (i'm used to English for tech) even tho i live in a Spanish speaking country.

Now heres the question, is there a way to set Android Auto to Spanish for example without changing the entire phone setting? Other people than me might want to use the head unit and would have to use English.

And then here's another interesting thing, when using the TTS feature to read messages, obviously its impossible to understand anything when reading Spanish with an English voice but what happens if i have messages in both Spanish and English, wouldn't it be nice to have it auto detect the language and use the appropriate TTS system regardless of the phone language?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: What worked for me was setting the search & voice language inside the Google App to German. Voice commands / TTS is now German while the UI is still English (my prefered way).

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same question today, I tried using http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings to change Android Auto locale settings, and it sort of worked... the home notifications are in Spanish now (i.e. shows "X mensajes nuevos"), but the maps, music, and notification aloud reading are still in English, I will try setting other components to Spanish later (whenever I have time), but let us know if you find something useful first.

Comment: What I ended doing (and worked), was to use Tasker + SecureSettings to change my android phone locale to Spanish when connected to my car, and to english when disconnected. Not the most elegant solution, but it did work, and the language change process is fairly quick.

Answer (score 0):

I use the xposed App settings module mentioned early, and change the android auto locale, but also change the google search app locale and notifications and voice recognition work in Spanish